# Hidden TextView on top of TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, swift2

I am creating an app to display a tableView. So far so good.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let content = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    @IBOutlet var textView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    extView = tableView.tableHeaderView
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.content.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = content[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        tableView.tableHeaderView = textView

    }
}
```

**The Main.storyboard**

[image]

**The Simulator**

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Add a **View** on top of the **TableView**.
- Inside the **View** add a **TextView** with some text.

I can do this. But i'd like the the ViewController to load only showing the table and when the user scrolldown the TexView appears. Like a Table Header hidden.

Comment: You set table y position 64. Because navigation bar height 64.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if(velocity.y>0){
            NSLog("dragging Up");
        }else{
            NSLog("dragging Down");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Write your code inside this method. But this method will call both for scroll down and scroll up. So, you need to detect scroll down customizing.

Comment: I've updated my code. Is this what you mean? When I scroll the view appears but suddenly. I'd like it to start scrolling down. Like it was hidden.

Comment: Ok it's working. Thank you. How can add an effect for the text to be with less opacity as the text appears?

Comment: wait man! this is not the procedure when you want the text view will scrolling down as other cell of tableview. The right way is adding the text view in the cell of  0 index of the table view. or add text view in 0 section of table view and the other 'one', 'two'... in the section 1.

Comment: set the opacity of the text view [0-1]. it will decrease the opacity of text of that textView.  say, yourTextview.alpha = 0.5;

Comment: Hmm. Can you please provide an example? How can I force the table to start at 1 cell and hide 0 cell?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by the following way.It will work if the total rows are enough to scroll(e.g tableheight=rowHeight*totalRow'it will not work. To work this you need to be tricky. if(tableheight>=rowHeight*totalRow){ tableheight = rowHeight*totalRow- fisrtRowHeight }

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if(objects.count>1){
        let indexPathStart = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPathStart, atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
    }
}
```